# Creating MvvmCross Application using V3 - System.Windows missing on iOS

Tags: xamarin.ios, mvvmcross, xamarin-studio

I currently try to setup my app using V3.

Works actually fine for WP8 and Android. But I'm strugeling over iOS.

As described in the new tutorial I've added the following references to my Core-Project:

- Cirrious.CrossCore.dll
- Cirrious.MvvmCross.dll

When I open my solution on my mac (got a solution which only includes the iOS and the Core project) Xamarin Studio starts to complain, that it can not find the System.Windows.Input stuff which is needed for the ICommand.

Currently it does not find ICommand/IList/MvxRealyCommand in the code... :S

So the question:
Which dll's I've to reference ein the core project to make it work in Xamarin Studio?

---

edit:
Ok, I've to add the following references to my Core-Project:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Net" />
    <Reference Include="System.Runtime.Serialization" />
    <Reference Include="System.ServiceModel" />
    <Reference Include="System.Windows" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Serialization" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Not sure whether I need all of them, just copy pasted them from the Conference-Example.
I've to do some more researches on this :S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update June 2013**

Xamarin has now released their first PCL support.

Further, one simple workaround for this issue has been found: simply don't use `MvxCommand` but instead use your own local-project `MyCommand` implementation of `System.Windows.Input.ICommand` as part of your `Core` project.

**End of Update**

---

Xamarin doesn't yet support PCLs properly

As a result you must compile your pcl projects separately for ios builds - and you must reference dll's built for iOS rather than dll's built for 'proper PCL'

When following the current mvx walkthrough this just means that you need to use different mvvmcross binaries on the Mac. I generally do this by just putting different dll files in /lib/mvx folder

The repo https://github.com/slodge/mvvmcross-binaries contains four sets of binaries currently - these cover all of pcl and ios, debug and release

---

More on this situation is available in http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/almost-portable-binaries.html?m=1

---

Hopefully this situation is changing soon - as soon as proper PCL support arrives then we should be able to use the same set of binaries on all platforms :)

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer! But it does not change anything when I use the Mac-dlls. There is simply something missing.. I've already tried to add "System.Windows.Touch" to the Core project. ICommand is still missing.. grr

Comment: Ok, I've checked the conference-example and I can compile it now. Do not completly understand why and have to investigate it further, but thanks for sending me in the right direction :-)